# How to exclude the validation in case of the specific nested attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm using one address model with polymorphic.

```
   Class Address < ApplicationRecord
        belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true, touch: true
        ...
        validates :street_address_1, presence: {with true, message:'cannot be blank'}
        validates :street_address_2, presence: {with true, message:'cannot be blank'}
        validates :city, presence: {with true, message:'cannot be blank'}
        validates :locale, presence: {with true, message:'cannot be blank'}
        validates :postal_code, presence: {with true, message:'cannot be blank'}
        validates :country, presence: {with true, message:'cannot be blank'}
        ...     
   end
```

Company model

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
   ...
   has_many :physical_addresses, :as=> addressable, dependent: :destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :physical_addresses, allow_destroy: true
   ...
end
```

User model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   ...
   has_many :physical_addresses, :as=> addressable, dependent: :destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :physical_addresses, allow_destroy: true
   ...
end
```

I'm using the nested attribute for creating or updating the User and Company controller.
I'd like to apply the address validation only for User creating and updating. But the companies don't have to be applied the address validation.

Is there any best way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a [validator](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validates-with) class.

Skip the validations if addressable refers to a Company.

```
def validate(address)
  return unless address.addressable.kind_of?(User)
  ...
end
```